# Swift Placeholder issue

Tags: placeholder, swift

I have this code

```
var i = 1
println(i) //result is 1   
println(%02i) //is wrong
```

I want it to output 01 instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't format swift strings like that (as far as I know.) You can try to use an NSString though.

```
println(NSString(format:"%02i", i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it

```
var i = 1
 NSLog("%02d", i)
```

O/P - 01

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is still going to be NSString formatting:

```
var i = 3
println("someInt is now \(i)")
// prints "someInt is now 1"
println(NSString(format:"%.2f",i))
// prints "someInt is now 01"
```

May be this help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
var i = 1
println("0\(i)")

//01
```