# ios swift proper float to string conversion

Tags: ios, swift

So in Obj-c this would be done differently, but I was wondering if anyone had any idea how to do this in swift? I feel embarrased having to ask this, but simply cannot find any documentation on it, how do I convert a float to string?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var userScore = receivePlayerCard?.playerScore

    var convertUserScoreToString: Float

    scoreNameLabel.text = convertUserScoreToString //need to convert it to a string here
    scoreNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert float value to String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123312/convert-float-value-to-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd do it like this:

```
scoreNameLabel.text = "\(convertUserScoreToString)"
```

[String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_381)

Comment: Wouldn't you want to specify a format string, too? Floats look very weird sometimes.

Comment: @Thilo There are ways of doing with that with NSString, but not with a Swift string as far as I know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24052540/754604 This works for simple interpolation though

Comment: @Thilo see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

We can use format strings with Swift's `String` type, thanks to Obj-C bridging!

So for example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userScore: Double = receivePlayerCard?.playerScore

    scoreNameLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", userScore)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```